# Conditional .htaccess for multisite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having a minor trouble in `.htaccess` file, I have looked into some stack links, but couldn't resolve my issue.

I have hosted a multi domain site, what I want is: **If there is a subdomain and I access this url**:

```
subdomain1.example.com/sitemap.xml
subdomain2.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

This should pick up the **sitemap.xml** file from `subdomains/subdomain1` and `subdomains/subdomain2` respectively, which works great with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example(.*).com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(sitemap.xml|robots.txt)$ subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC]
```

If there is `www.example.com` then pickup the **sitemap.xml** from project root folder.

I have tried this, but not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(sitemap.xml|robots.txt)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

It gives me `500 internal server` error.

Comment: Whenever you encounter a 500 error, the absolute first thing you do is always go and check the server’s error logs.

Comment: It leads me to redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx condition in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example(.*).com [NC]` matches even `www.example.com`, so there will be a redirect loop.

The rewrite condition alternative that you specified as `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]` won't work as it is does not match `www.example.com`

Try this Regex condition

`^(?!www).*\.example(.*).com`

OR

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www).*\.example(.*).com [NC]`

Comment: That's working, I made a minor change to do so, ^(?!www)(.*)\.example(.*).com